# WebCore: Worker: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when connecting Safari debugger to an Xcode 8.3 project

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, safari

I just upgraded to Xcode 8.3 because Apple.  I've created a Cordova project that has worked flawlessly on previous Xcode versions, but now there's a problem.  I deploy the app to the Simulator, and whenever I try to connect the Safari Debugger (Safari > Develop > Simulator > Test App), the app crashes with:

> WebCore: Worker (25): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

[image: Xcode WebCore: Worker: EXC_BAD_ACCESS]

I'm running Cordova 6.5.0 and there are no plugins installed.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Update**: So it looks like WebWorkers are the culprit. If I disable our WebWorker code in the project, the debugger connects without a problem. It's nice to know that this is the issue, but disabling WebWorkers isn't really a solution, so if anyone has any ideas, I'm all ears.

Comment: Great catch!  I've been fighting this all afternoon.  "new Worker('xyz.js')" seems to be all it takes to cause the crash behavior.

Comment: I've filed a bug report in Radar.  Hopefully Apple releases an update.  Seems to be a combination of Xcode Version 8.3 (8E162) and Safari Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34).  Does not seem to be an issue with Safari 10.0 and Xcode 8.3.

Comment: Just for the record, the EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash still occurs with Xcode 8.3.2 (8E2002), iOS 10.3.1, and Safari 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34).

Comment: Agreed that disabling the WebWorker code is not a good solution... Really not sure why this is happening but it makes working with cordova on ios a lot more difficult...

Comment: I see there is not fix from Apple yet. Luckily I am using a library that allow my webworkers to be disable but when is time to deploy it will be a nightmare...

Comment: I forgot to add, I can just debug with safari if I run the project from Xcode, if I run it from `cordova run ios` still crashes.

Comment: After updating xcode 9.0 and safari 11 I was finally able to get it work. Looks like the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely something that Apple needs to resolve.

In the meantime, downloading and using iOS 10.2 Simulator fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of web worker due to some internal Safari error. Try commenting out your web worker piece.